# Anyone know where I can download the PHP7 equivalent of php_pdo_sqlsrv

Tags: php-7

Anyone know where I can download the PHP7 equivalent of pdo drivers for sql server?  Do they exist yet?

I've been hunting around google looking for them and haven't found anything.

I'm looking for a windows version x86 non thread safe.

Comment: Just to clarify your question: You are looking for a **Microsoft** SQL Server driver. For windows there's a PHP 5 driver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn865013.aspx but you haven't found a PHP 7 driver.

Comment: That is correct, though the link you provide is not for the pdo drivers

Comment: Have you tried ODBC? The link I used was mentioned on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: I have the ODBC drivers installed and the sqlsrv drivers installed (which now require the ODBC drivers and C++2015 runtime).  It is the PDO drivers that I am looking for.